# React App Not Rendering When Using JS in HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to building apps using React. After downloading the 'Getting Started' app directly from the [repo](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#getting-started) I started the server and the default app rendered properly. I tried to add a Menu component by following the tutorial [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dannymarkov/vfcfndxj/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=vfcfndxj), but the app fails to render after compiling with no errors. For more context, this app is saved in a file called App.js, not a file with .jsx extension.

I think the issue is with the insertion of JS code via {} into the HTML within `MenuExample.render()`. If I replace the body of `MenuExample.render()` with the simple HTML code commented out in the function, the app renders. Can someone please shed some light as to why the app isn't rendering? Thanks for all the help.

Please see the full code below.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

/* eslint no-var:0*/
/* eslint func-names:0*/
/* eslint prefer-arrow-callback:0*/
/* eslint class-methods-use-this:0*/
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <MenuExample items={ ['Home', 'Services', 'About', 'Contact Us'] }/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class MenuExample extends Component {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  getInitialState() {
    return { focused: 0 };
  }

  clicked(index) {
    this.setState({ focused: index });
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line
  render() {
    var self = this;

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{this.props.items.map(function (m, index) {
          var style = '';

          if (self.state.focused === index) {
            style = 'focused';
          }

          return <li className={style} onClick={self.clicked.bind(self, index)}>{m}</li>;
        }) }
        </ul>

        <p> Selected: {this.props.items[this.state.focused]} </p>
      </div>

      // Simple HTML that works
      // <p> Foo </p>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: any error in chrome console?

Comment: No, there were no errors in the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use the `getInitialState` lifecycle method inside your react component created using `es6` classes, which isn't supported. You should change to a constructor and setting your initial state inside of it.

```
class MenuExample extends Component {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { focused: 0 };
  }
  ...
```

It is explained [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the reference!